# MS DOS - Copy any number of files using parameters and SET

Tags: windows, batch-file, parameter-passing, dos

I have a problem a little silly on MS Dos, basically what I do is the following:

Assuming that we are located in C:\BATCH...
Copy any number of files in the directory C:\BATCH passed as parameters to the directory 
J:\TEXTS. Detect:

1. - That destination directory exists and if not, create it.
2. - Identify which parameters passed.
3. - Indicate whether to copy the file there.

I've tried but do not know what part to put the parameters. Also try to equal the value of a variable to a parameter but I think that it cant do.

I leave what I did, but I've used parameters.

```
@echo off
if not exist J:\texts\nul md J:\texts
set dir=J:\texts
cls

:continue
set /p file="File to copy (END to finish) "
if %file%==END goto end
if not exist %file% goto error1
cls
echo You will copy the file %file% into directory %dir%
pause
cls
copy %file% %dir% >nul
goto loopback

:loopback
goto continue

:error1
cls
echo The file %file% doesnt exist.

:end
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are passed as `%1`, `%2`, etc. So if you call

```
YourScript.bat "foo.txt" "bar.txt"
```

, then the variable `%1` will contain `"foo.txt"` and `%2` will contain `"bar.txt"`.

To support a variable number of parameters, you can use the command `shift`. It will shift all parameters back one step, so %2 becomed %1, %3 becomes %2 and so on.

So, inside a loop, you can move the file in `%1`, then call `shift`, and repeat that until `%1` is empty.

```
@echo off

rem  Initialization goes here

:start

rem  Check if there are files left.
if %1X==X goto done

echo Copying %1
rem  Actual copying goes here. Maybe some checking
rem  if file exists and stuff like that.
shift
goto start

:done
echo Done.
```

PS: I see the label 'error1' in your script. Don't be afraid to use a more descriptive name. You will thank yourself if you got 10 or more types of errors.